# Dynamically toggling tinymce toolbar with checkbox for multiple ID's?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have multiple text boxes in a form that open with the tinymce toolbar loaded in them.
Here are some of the text areas'

```
<p id="rsvpInfo" style="display:none;"><label class="leftLabel">RSVP Info</label><textarea name="rsvp_info" rows="10" cols="50" class="contact mceNoEditor mceBasicEditor"></textarea></p>



<p id="abstract" style="display:none;"><label class="leftLabel">Abstract</label><textarea name="abstract" rows="10" cols="50" class="contact mceNoEditor mceBasicEditor"></textarea></p>
```

I am trying to make a check box outside the form which is initially **checked**. Once i uncheck it, then all of the tinmcy toolbars disappear and only plain text area are displayed and vice versa.

I decided to use the following code (outside the form) to implement my idea but it seems as if I am doing something wrong as nothing happens on checking/unchecking the checkbox.

```
<script>
    var id = 'speakerInfo';
    var id1= 'rsvpInfo';
    var id2= 'abstract';
    var id3= 'speakerBios';

    if($("#mceCheck".is(':checked'))
    {
        tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',false, id);
        tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',false, id1);
        tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',false, id2);
        tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',false, id3);
    }
    else
    {
        tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false, id);
        tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false, id1);
        tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false, id2);
        tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false, id3);
    }
</script>
```

Here is the code for the checkbox:

```
 <form>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mce" value="1" id="mceCheck" checked> tinyMCE toolbar toggle checkbox
    </form>
```

Can someone help me out with the jquery to dynamically change the visibilty of the tinyMCE toolbar with a checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you didn't handle checkbox change event.

jQuery [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event

```
$("#mceCheck").change(function(e) {
    //Do something here
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      //Do something when the checkbox is checked
    }
    else
    {
      //Unchecked case
    }
});
```

Comment: got it, but won't this just handle one case (i.e if i change the value of the checkbox?) . How will this be able to change back if checkbox is unselected or selected?

Comment: @user2441391 you can check if the checkbox is selected/unselected using `$(this).is(:checked)` .. see my edited answer

Comment: thanks, i have implemented the logic you said. But the tinymce toolbars are still not going away. Is there a problem with the tinymce function i have used?

Comment: @user2441391 are you using ajax to load this checkbox or page?

Comment: No, i am not. Will that make a difference?